# Error when scaffolding Controller for new WEB Api application

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a new WEB Api application and added a new Model class. The problem is that when I try to scaffold a new controller for it I keep getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyP9P.png). I tried searching for a solution but I haven't found anyone that has encountered this specific error.

" There was an error running the selected code generator: 'The value -1 is outside the acceptable range of[0,2147483647]. Parameter name:value' "

This is my model class:

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you linking it to Entity Framework? Are you assigning `-1` to `ID` ?

Comment: I tried generating it using EF. And no, the db is not yet populated and the ID is set to auto-increment in Microsoft SQL Management Studio

Comment: Aren't you using Code First? Have you got any entry into the already? The power of EF is supposed to handle everything by the code and deploy migrations, so you might not change anything on Management Studio. Give a try to [Key annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys).

Comment: No, I am using Database-First Approach.